# Regex for accepting Persian characters in address

Tags: c#, regex, persian

Here is my regex for testing address:

`^((([\u0600-\u06FF])+\s?([0-9()،,-]?)+\s?))+$`

but when address contains `/` or `\` character, `RegexMatchTimeoutException` occurs.

here is sample input:

`"تهران - خیابان سهروردی - خیابان 19 شرقی، کوچه 59, پلاک 39525، / طبقه ٣"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that it contains nested quantifiers that quantify optional patterns.

Use linear logic:

```
^[\u0600-\u06FF]+(?:[\s0-9()،,-]+[\u0600-\u06FF]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%5Cu0600-%5Cu06FF%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5B%5Cs0-9%28%29%D8%8C%2C-%5D%2B%5B%5Cu0600-%5Cu06FF%5D%2B%29*%5Cr%3F%24&i=%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86%20-%20%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D8%B3%D9%87%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF%DB%8C%20-%20%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%2019%20%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%82%DB%8C%D8%8C%20%DA%A9%D9%88%DA%86%D9%87%2059%2C%20%D9%BE%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%A9%2039525%D8%8C%20%2F%20%D8%B7%D8%A8%D9%82%D9%87%20%D9%A3%0D%0A%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86%20-%20%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D8%B3%D9%87%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF%DB%8C%20-%20%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%2019%20%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%82%DB%8C%D8%8C%20%DA%A9%D9%88%DA%86%D9%87%2059%2C%20%D9%BE%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%A9%2039525%D8%8C%20%D8%B7%D8%A8%D9%82%D9%87%20%D9%A3%0D%0A%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86%20-%20%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D8%B3%D9%87%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF%DB%8C%20-%20%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%2019%20%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%82%DB%8C%D8%8C%20%DA%A9%D9%88%DA%86%D9%87%2059%2C%20%D9%BE%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%A9%2039525%D8%8C%20%D8%B7%D8%A8%D9%82%D9%87%20%D9%A3%20%2F&o=m)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[\u0600-\u06FF]+` - 1 or more symbols from the given Unicode range
- `(?:[\s0-9()،,-]+[\u0600-\u06FF]+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `[\s0-9()،,-]+` - 1+ symbols: either whitespace, digits, `(`, `)`, `،`, `,` or `-`
  - `[\u0600-\u06FF]+` - 1 or more symbols from the given Unicode range
- `$` - end of string.